# How do I make each page of my assignment have a different page number?

Tags: google-docs

Every time I go to number my pages with the Google Docs Insert "thing", it makes all of my page numbers say "1". I've tried to change it manually, but it changes together. If I replace the `1` on the second page with a `2`, all of my pages say "2" at the top.

How do I fix it, or is this something that is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe things have since changed or you weren't doing it right. This works for me:

[image: WA90976 first example]

though for testing I have only print viewed it:
[image: WA90976 second example]